# How to fill a KeyValue Pair from an IList +C#.net

Tags: c#, list, datetime, generics

I have an `IList` as follows:

```
IList<AnodeCharacteristicsComposite> anodeNoDateTimesOverall =
    _dataContext.GetAnodeDetails(startTime, endTime, anodeNoPattern).ToList();
```

Where `AnodeCharacteristicsComposite` is a class which has got two attributes

```
public class AnodeCharacteristicsComposite 
{
    [Column(DbType = "nvarchar(50)")]
    public string AnodeStamp { get; set; }

    [Column(DbType = "datetime")]
    public DateTime ProductionDate { get; set; }
}
```

`GetAnodeDetails(startTime, endTime, anodeNoPattern)` is a stored procedure which will give the list of `AnodeStamp`, `ProductionDate` for the selected time period.

Now I want to form an `IList<Pair<string, DateTime>>` from the above List `anodeNoDateTimesOverall`  and use it for some other calculations.

```
IList<Pair<string, DateTime>> anodeNoDateTimes =
    anodeNoDateTimesOverall.ToDictionary(x => x.AnodeStamp, x => x.ProductionDate);
```

I tried like this but its not working. Can someone please help me how to do this?

Comment: What does 'it's not working' mean?  And could you sort the formatting, it's hard to tell if you have a non-generic `IList` or a generic `IList<T>`.  If it's the former, that might explain your issue.

Comment: IList<AnodeCharacteristicsComposite> anodeNoDateTimesOverall = _dataContext.GetAnodeDetails(startTime, endTime, anodeNoPattern).ToList();    when I am converting the IList to a Pair like the below it gives error :                                                                                    
IList<Pair<string, DateTime>> anodeNoDateTimes =anodeNoDateTimesOverall.ToDictionaryt(X => X.AnodeStamp, x => x.ProductionDate);

Comment: `ToDictionary<TKey, TValue>()` returns a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, not an `IList<Pair<TKey, TValue>>`. Also, there is an overload of `ToDictionary()` that only takes a key selector, using the original list as the values (`anodeNoDateTimesOverall.ToDictionary(x => x.AnodeStamp);`)

Comment: Thanks Kai. Can u pls give an example.I have not understood completely what u meant.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about `KeyValue` pairs? If so use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` where in your case it will be `Dictionary<string, DateTime>` instead of `List<T>`

Answer (score 0):

`ToDictionary` return a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, not an IList.

Your program doesn't compile.

If you really do need the `IList<Pair<string, DateTime>>`, you can build it with something like

```
IList<Pair<string, DateTime>> anodeNoDateTimes =
   anodeNoDateTimesOverall
   .Select(x => Pair.Create(x.AnodeStamp, x.ProductionDate).ToList();
```

depending of course on your `Pair` type, and whether it has such a create method.

Comment: Yes.Thanks Kris, it failes. Is there any way where I can fill a  IList<Pair<string, DateTime>> anodeNoDateTimes from an IList

Comment: thanks. it was useful however, it doesnt have a create method.Error 114 'Keops.Common.Utilities.Pair' does not contain a definition for 'Create'

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your tips. I have done it finally

```js
 IList<AnodeCharacteristicsComposite> anodeNoDateTimesOverall = _dataContext.GetAnodeDetails(startTime, endTime, anodeNoPattern).ToList();
                IList<Pair<string, DateTime>> anodeNoDateTimes=

             
                (from ap in anodeNoDateTimesOverall
                      
                        select Pair.From(ap.AnodeStamp, ap.ProductionDate))
                                      .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for giving credit to (and upvoting) my answer.